# Making pages that can be displayed only if logged in - ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have always been programming with ASP.NET Web Forms. Everything was simpler but now for having better performance and modern software, I decided to switch to ASP.NET MVC.

I managed to understand most of the concepts but due to lack of Page Lifecyle in MVC, I am having troubles verifying whether the user has logged in.

Let me give you an example:

In ASP.NET Web Forms, I use to make a login page where if the user exists and has given proper credentials, the program would create a `Session` variable like this: `Session["UserID"] = 3;`

And when the user is navigated to his or her account page, the a code like the one below would check if the user is logged in:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Session["UserID"]==null)
        {
             Response.Redirect("/login.aspx");
        }
    }
```

how to make the same thing in MVC?

Comment: One *could* do pretty much the same thing in ASP.NET MVC, though that's not really a great pattern to follow. Have you looked at any of the [documentation about authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/)? There's lots of info there about how to set up proper authentication and authorization.

Comment: There is most assuredly a page [lifecycle in MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `[Authorize]` above your function. You could add it above your controller if you want all the functions to be available to logged-in users.

If you do this, don't forget to add `app.UseAuthorization();` in your Program.cs file

Tell me if this helps ^^

Comment: yep, doing this is the solution to my problem. Thank you very much